# how to set unique ID to instances

Tags: java, unique, instance

I'm trying to create instances of the `class product` that has a unique identifier(ID).

The ID will act like the barcode on the products at a store, and the user may change the ID after adding a product.

This is what I have so far:

```
public class Product {

    private int id;
    //and some other attributes...

    public Product (int id){
        this.id = id;
    }


    public void setId(){
        this.Id = id;
    }

    //more not relevant methods...
    }
```

I was thinking of creating a class that will contain all the created  products something like this:

```
public class Inventory{

    ArrayList<Product> products;
    //not sure if I should use product array or ID's array

    public Producto createProduct(int id){
        if (products.contains(/* product with id*/)){
            // not sure what to use here
        }
        else{
          return new Producto(id);
        }
    }

}
```

so I'm not sure how to make it work, or if the `class Inventory` is a good idea.

Comment: May be you can add a method which adds an instance of `Product` to an instance of `Inventory`. This method would be called in the constructor of `Product`. I advise you write a `getter()` in class `Product` if it isn't done yet.

Comment: thank you. @Badda
yes, I already made a getter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may modify the `Inventory` class to hold a datastructure like below

```
HashMap<Integer, Product> products;
```

Initialize it in the constructor, and then you can call `products.contains(<int id>)`. You need to add new product to this data-structure accordingly.

For correct and efficient use of `HashMap`, you would also need to read about overriding `equals()` and `hashcode()` method. `HashMap` gives you O(1) insertion and O(1) lookup.

Comment: HashMap, I dont know how to use it, but I have heard about it.
Thanks , I'll do my research.  :)